# Why do we need to destroy lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, performance

I was looking at this blog post about [Dynamically Instantiate and destroy Lightning Components – Modal dialog component](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/dynamically-instantiate-and-destroy-lightning-components-modal-dialog-component/) and author is instantiating, destroying child component from the code.

But I was able to replicate similar output without doing all(instantiating and destroying from code) of that so curious about the whole concept of destroying components programmatically.

1. Why do we need to destroy lightning components from the code?
2. Don't lightning components get destroyed when user navigates to
   different url/page?
3. I think destroying components is something similar to garbage collection in java but besides performance improvements or there are any functional bugs in my implementation below:

**ExampleOne.app:**

```
<aura:attribute name="input1" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="input2" type="String"/>

<div aura:id="parent-div-id">

    <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-6 slds-m-around--xx-small">
        <ui:inputText label="param 1" value="{!v.input1}"  class="slds-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-6 slds-m-around--xx-small">
        <ui:inputText label="param 2" value="{!v.input2}"  class="slds-input"/>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-size--1-of-6 slds-m-around--xx-large slds-clearfix">
        <ui:button label="Open Modal Dialog" 
                    press="{!c.openModal}" 
                    class="slds-button slds-button--destructive slds-float--right"  />
    </div>

    <!-- Modal for editing schedules -->
    <div role="dialog" id="child-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header44" class="slds-modal">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <c:ModalComponent aura:id="childCmp"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.closeModal}">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>        

    <div id="modal-backdrop" class="slds-backdrop"></div>
</div>
```

**ExampleOneController.js:**

```
({
    openModal : function(component, event, helper) {

        var schChildComp = component.find('childCmp');
        schChildComp.loadData(component.get('v.input1'),component.get('v.input2'));

        var rootElem = component.find('parent-div-id').getElement();

        var modalElem = rootElem.querySelector('#child-modal');
        modalElem.className = 'slds-modal slds-fade-in-open';
        var modalBackDropElem = rootElem.querySelector('#modal-backdrop');
        modalBackDropElem.className = 'slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open';        
        return false;
    },
    closeModal : function(component){
        var rootElem = component.find('parent-div-id').getElement();

        var modalElem = rootElem.querySelector('#child-modal');
        modalElem.className = 'slds-modal';
        var modalBackFropElem = rootElem.querySelector('#modal-backdrop');
        modalBackFropElem.className = 'slds-backdrop'; 
    }
})
```

**ModalComponent.cmp:**

```
<aura:attribute name="arg1" type="String"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="arg2" type="String"></aura:attribute>

<aura:method name="loadData" action="{!c.loadData}"> 
    <aura:attribute name="p1" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="p2" type="String"/>
</aura:method> 

Value 1 passed from parent: <aura:text value="{!v.arg1}"></aura:text><br/>
Value 2 passed from parent: <aura:text value="{!v.arg2}"></aura:text>
```

**ModalComponentController.js:**

```
({
    loadData : function(component, event, helper) {
        debugger;
        var params = event.getParam('arguments');
        component.set("v.arg1",params.p1);
        component.set("v.arg2",params.p2);
    }
})
```

Output:

[image]

**NOTE**: I am not seeing any lightning component related warnings in browser console.

Comment: A very detailed answer, not specific to Lightning itself: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jsmemory/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only time you need to call destroy explicitly is if you never add it to a body. If you do so, it will be destroyed automatically once removed. This is in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm):

> **Destroying Dynamically Created Components**
>
> After a component that is declared in markup is no longer in use, the
>   framework automatically destroys it and frees up its memory.
>
> If you create a component dynamically in JavaScript and that component
>   isn't added to a facet (v.body or another attribute of type
>   Aura.Component[]), you have to destroy it manually using
>   Component.destroy() to avoid memory leaks.

So, in the general case, you don't ever need to call destroy, unless you never assigned it anywhere. The framework will clean up after you.

## Q & A

> Why do we need to destroy lightning components from the code?

You're not creating anything (there's no $A.createComponent), so no need to worry about destroying anything.

> Don't lightning components get destroyed when user navigates to different url/page?

Yes, but they also get destroyed when they're no longer in the DOM anywhere. Remember that Lightning is a Single Page Application, and so the browser doesn't load/unload the page repeatedly. This provides a smoother user experience.

> I think destroying components is something similar to garbage collection in java but besides performance improvements or there are any functional bugs in my implementation below

This implementation is just fine. The framework will create/destroy your components for you.

Comment: So in my case, I don't need to destroy component because it is in the markup and not injected from JS?

Comment: @javanoob Yes, I was actually editing in more details to answer your sub-questions, but in summary, if you don't create it, you don't need to destroy it.

Comment: @sfdcfox If we create a component dynamically and add to body, how to remove the component from body when we destroy the component using component.destroy(). ?

Comment: I understand that framework destroys the component but the reference from body attribute is not getting updated. For example: length of body  attribute is still showing the same as it is supposed to reduce on destroy.

Comment: @brahmajitammana That's not how destroy works. *You*, the developer, must remove the component from the body if you set it there. Calling destroy on a component that is in use may have undesirable side effects, so don't do it. And, as stated in this answer, do not ever explicitly call destroy unless you never added the component to a body attribute.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for your reply. Can you help me in finding the correct component from body attribute. I have created a componentNumber attribute in my dynamic component and appending 1 on every instance creation. But when slice the body attribute with index as component number, it is not working in all the cases. because component number is constant and array length will reduce each time. What is the best way of finding my component in body attribute and to remove it ?

Comment: @brahmajitammana You may want to ask a new question, but the simple answer would be to "filter" for it: `component.set("v.body", component.get("v.body").filter(item => item.get("v.componentNumber") != componentNumberToRemove));`

Comment: is there any difference for destroying a component using `component.set('body', [])` or `mycomponent.destroy()` ?

Comment: @Bryce Use destroy if the component was never set to an attribute, otherwise there is no need to do so, as the framework automatically calls destroy for you when you update the attribute.